# Can't install JRE on Win8 VM

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, java

I'm running a Windows 8 x86 VM in Oracle Virtualbox, on a Windows 8 x64 host (don't ask why, I don't know either), and I need to install the Java Runtime Environment on it, but I'm having problems doing that.

When I run the downloader/installer which the java website offers by default, it gets stuck about halfway through the download and doesn't seem to recover. So I tried downloading the full installer and run that, after confirming the UAC prompt I get the "loading" mouse pointer animation for a brief second, but nothing happens after that. When I check the task manager, I see one background process called 'Java(TM) Platform SE binary' using 1.3 megs of ram, but not doing anything.

Anybody got an idea how to fix this / a workaround to still get java installed?

Comment: Did you get latest version? Did you try to run this program in capability mode ?

Comment: Yes I got the latest version, and I also tried several older ones I found in my download folder, same thing. Compatibility mode (assuming that's what you meant) doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe it but I just fixed the problem.

It would appear that Windows Action Center was running some automated maintenance tasks, and that apparently screwed with the Java installer. I cancelled it and now the installation works just fine, with both the online and offline installers.